# Downloading a PDF file with DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a PDF file from a server.

External storage is saved:

> static final File fSdcard = new
>   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "VDTEC");

Name of file:

> static final File fManualMult = new File(fSdcard, "ManualMult.pdf");

The Download ID

> private long lDownloadID;

And the URL:

> static final String sUrlManualMult = "http://germipasto.com.br/comunicacao/app/MULT/MANUAL%20VD%20TEC%20MULT%20-%20revis%C3%A3o%2001%20-%2002-fev%202018.pdf";

When I press the button, the "beginDownload" method is called:

> private void beginDownload(){
>
> ```
>     /*
>     Create a DownloadManager.Request with all the information necessary to start the download
>      */
>
>     DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(sUrlManualMult))
>             .setMimeType("application/pdf")
>             .setTitle("Dummy File")// Title of the Download Notification
>             .setDescription("Downloading")// Description of the Download Notification
>             .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)// Visibility of the download Notification
>             .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(fManualMult))// Uri of the destination file
>             .setRequiresCharging(false)// Set if charging is required to begin the download
>             .setAllowedOverMetered(true)// Set if download is allowed on Mobile network
>             .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);// Set if download is allowed on roaming network
>     request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
>     DownloadManager downloadManager= (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
>     lDownloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);// enqueue puts the download request in the queue.
> }
> ```

I also have a broadcaster that shows a toast when the download is completed:

> private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver()
>   {
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         //Fetching the download id received with the broadcast
>         long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
>         //Checking if the received broadcast is for our enqueued download by matching download id
>         if (lDownloadID == id) {
>             Toast.makeText(DocumentosActivity.this, "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

And register it:

> registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

The problem is:
When I click, the Toast is shown in 1-2 sec and the download is not completed.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have found that if a change the link (ex: using http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db directly) the downloadmanager works.
Could be an error with my link?
I uploaded the file via ftp and it can be accessed via browser.

Comment: SHow the code that registers for the download complete.  Sounds like you're confusing a status update with completion

Comment: the code shown at the end (private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {) doesn't do this job? @GabeSechan

Comment: No.  That creates a broadcast receiver, it doesn't register it.  All that does is create a variable.

Comment: oh, you're right. here is the code: registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)); @GabeSechan (i will add it in the post). Read the PS, i found out it now